# How exactly do recursive conditional types work?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types, nested-generics

```js
  export type Parser = NumberParser | StringParser;

  type NumberParser = (input: string) => number | DiplomacyError;
  type StringParser = (input: string) => string | DiplomacyError;

  export interface Schema {
    [key: string]: Parser | Schema;
  }

  export type RawType<T extends Schema> = {
    [Property in keyof T]: T[Property] extends Schema
      ? RawType<T[Property]>
      : ReturnType<Exclude<T[Property], Schema>>;
  };


  // PersonSchema is compliant the Schema interface, as well as the address property
  const PersonSchema = {
    age: DT.Integer(DT.isNonNegative),
    address: {
      street: DT.String(),
    },
  };

  type Person = DT.RawType<typeof PersonSchema>;
```

Sadly `type Person` is inferred as:

```
type Person = {
    age: number | DT.DiplomacyError;
    address: DT.RawType<{
        street: StringParser;
    }>;
}
```

Instead I would have liked to get:

```
type Person = {
    age: number | DT.DiplomacyError;
    address: {
        street: string | DT.DiplomacyError;
    };
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like those are the same type; just displayed differently.  I will verify when I get a chance.  There are ways to convince the compiler to expand the type... not really equipped to answer this minute as I’m on mobile.

Comment: Assigning a string to address.street does in fact work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the `Person` displayed and the type you expected is pretty much just cosmetic.  The compiler has a set of heuristic rules it follows when evaluating and displaying types.  These rules have changed over time and are occasionally tweaked, such as the ["smarter type alias preservation"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#smarter-type-alias-preservation) support introduced in TypeScript 4.2.

One way to see that the types are more or less equivalent is to create both of them:

```
type Person = RawType<PersonSchema>;
/*type Person = {
    age: number | DiplomacyError;
    address: RawType<{
        street: StringParser;
    }>;
}*/

type DesiredPerson = {
    age: number | DiplomacyError;
    address: {
        street: string | DiplomacyError;
    };
}
```

And then see that the compiler considers them *mutually assignable*:

```
declare let p: Person;
let d: DesiredPerson = p; // okay
p = d; // okay
```

The fact that those lines did not result in a warning means that, according to the compiler, any value of type `Person` is also a value of type `DesiredPerson`, and vice versa.

So maybe that's enough for you.

---

If you really care about how the type is represented, you can use techniques such as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/2887218):

```
// expands object types recursively
type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
    ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> } : never
    : T;
```

If I compute `ExpandRecursively<Person>`, it walks down through `Person` and explicitly writes out each of the properties.  Assuming that `DiplomacyError` is this (for want of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question):

```
interface DiplomacyError {
    whatIsADiplomacyError: string;
}
```

Then `ExpandRecurively<Person>` is:

```
type ExpandedPerson = ExpandRecursively<Person>;
/* type ExpandedPerson = {
    age: number | {
        whatIsADiplomacyError: string;
    };
    address: {
        street: string | {
            whatIsADiplomacyError: string;
        };
    };
} */
```

which is closer to what you want.  In fact, you could rewrite `RawType` to use this technique, like:

```
type ExpandedRawType<T extends Schema> = T extends infer O ? {
    [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends Schema
    ? ExpandedRawType<O[K]>
    : O[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never;
} : never;

type Person = ExpandedRawType<PersonSchema>
/* type Person = {
    age: number | DiplomacyError;
    address: {
        street: string | DiplomacyError;
    };
} */
```

which is exactly the form you wanted.

(Side note: there is a naming convention for type parameters, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344160/2887218).  Single capital letters are preferred over whole words, so as to distinguish them from specific types.  Hence, I have replaced `Property` in your examples with `K` for "key".  It might seem paradoxical, but because of this convention, `K` is more likely to be immediately understood by TypeScript developers to be a generic property key than `Property` is.  You are, of course, free to continue using `Property` or anything else you like; it's just a convention, after all, and not some sort of commandment.  But I just wanted to point out that the convention exists.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCLAA4BsD2BbRATwFEoocpkBvAKGXuQHcALOMASQGcBBdbfIqXJQAXMk5gooAOYBuGgF8aNCAA8MFMMjCEMKAApwonaMgC8yAHIBXPACNoh46YA+yAMqSZTk1Hk0dPStbBygfUwsAClAMazAxCSkQaQBKcwA+ZBAQ1zRMXAIEEjIKeUCUTyTpcMoomLiEr2S0s0zEmWQ3PgLBEr9lNQ0oLVBIWEQKhGYIAmo6BgBtAGsIQkaqgF0xGs6PKZm4eSUVdU1tXRQAJThGABULgB5b5DVIEAATTj3pgkyLWgYyAWAGlkKBkCtCDgYMhbltYSCNi9VG9Pt8DvN6AB+ZDXO6PW6I9KY5BiS4QMDWKAge56B7EVQILDWd4QJ6IgA06N+6SO-nKyH00E4OBA7n2s3+JLg0ggYhs9kcRl8HOl73eUAgnE4YgBgIYiQgFLElW8yugJKUxwFQuMovMuJutLZtpFYolcF5NAA9AAqG3C+1SwEyuVZHKULr5ARFISlNUarU6x34ul6-XiSRG+IeJrVc39QEKL0KX3e5QC1Ba4Ca96uoNzEOysTZRWRvL8QrFYTyEPqzXa3UkwGG42Zqq7box7vxotHZSsplGFBYCnIDDbQMgeSrrTvMRVzg1iB1rcOjCyZDe73IHBLOCEGgYB3vS-X2-3x-Kd+DOAfL44HYABWEAIFo5QASAK4QAAbhAWDIKyEAYAEFzIAyGB-u8Tx-LCyKol8oAwKYADyyA4lQQKguCkLQsgJHwiRiLIAopJZLB0D+D+6hYQBwGgeBFxfJqCBUkecFYI+AoYVh5KicYwASYQOEOs8rwQP+t78WBJI4mpKIaWiRGkeR1BUWCIAQqsdEMWIMkfHJYmKfBylMcCGyZKxLYcVAJJiLc-ijNA8BIB2PSxn0jYMCwbBcLw0ZdnGojjjI84Vmh9msqedqWRYmWOQpSkPPWIBen65xBJlJ4lQ66bIKGLYRrsdWAjFHA8FOiV9OsqWWr2DBwP2SZDhm9Cjjm7TJM1w6jW1cWdb0wg9ck-UZgoq0sUcyBlullU8R8J54s6Tz4YZXzij8nqqadmnGZQZEUSSIIWVZUIwrZ9HMepmkXRigI4lV7xHY8bkeX5n3uTdaKRAAdHDRjSMmf6EC0mR3bipmXGxUFwf0Xnsbj-JoSVABMDqA8DdIlb9vw+r6FUGFuZPBgNzbhm2k4JYts4DUNg5RRm43LdInOdtzhYMOtijbd6QA)

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding why I need to "manually" infer the O type, but it did indeed work...

DiplomacyError is an enum mapping to strings and it doesn't seem to preserve the type alias, seems like the compiler is doing `string | DiplomacyError -> string | string -> string`

(Thank you so much.)

Comment: But that would be a whole different question :)